# NSMutableArray outputs wrong data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I'm using `Parse.com` as the backend of my app.

Each user has access to a list of `PFObjects`. If the current user wants to 'favorite' an object I'd like to remove it from the main list for the current user.

Below is my code, ran in `ObjectsDidLoad`.

If I log out the code below, the `PFObject` that is in the `PFRelation` is being removed, but in my `UITableView` the last item in the `NSMutableArray` is being removed.

Am I running this in the wrong location?

Maybe missing a step?

Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"myRelation"];
    PFQuery *relationQuery = relation.query;
    [relationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        NSMutableArray *arrayToShow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.objects];

        for (PFObject *object1 in self.objects) {
            for (PFObject *object2 in results) {
                if ([[object1 objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:[object2 objectForKey:@"title"]]) {
                    [arrayToShow removeObject:object1];
                }
            }
        }

        self.objectsToShowArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayToShow];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

More description:

Table A, or the main table, loads all objects in a Parse class. Every user will have access to this.

User selects an object to go to another view controller and can tap a button to add it to another Parse class. This also creates a PFRelation.

So if user adds object 'xyz' to Parse Class B and Table B, I want that object to not show in Table A for them (though it will have to stay in Parse Class A as every user has access to this).

So, I want to query on Parse Class A, query on the PFRelation, and remove matching objects out of the array that's displayed on Table A.

Here's my queryForTable method:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query orderByAscending:@"title"];

    // **********************************
    // PFRelation
    PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"myRelation"];
    PFQuery *relationQuery = relation.query;
    [relationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        NSMutableArray *arrayToShow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.objects];

        for (PFObject *object1 in self.objects) {
            for (PFObject *object2 in results) {
                if ([[object1 objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:[object2 objectForKey:@"title"]]) {
                    [arrayToShow removeObject:object1];
                }
            }
        }
        self.objectsToShowArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayToShow];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
    // **********************************

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSObject * object = [prefs objectForKey:@"category"];
    if(object != nil){
        //object is there
        self.categoryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object];

        [query whereKey:@"category" equalTo:self.categoryString];
    }

    // A pull-to-refresh should always trigger a network request.
    [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    //
    // If there is no network connection, we will hit the cache first.
    if (self.objects.count == 0 || ![[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:@selector(isParseReachable)]) {
        [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];
    }

    return query;
}
```

**Another attempt:**

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query orderByAscending:@"title"];

    // **********************************
    // PFRelation Query
    PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"myRelation"];
    PFQuery *relationQuery = relation.query;    
    [relationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        PFQuery *theQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
        [theQuery whereKey:@"title" matchesKey:@"title" inQuery:relationQuery];
        [theQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            NSMutableArray *arrayToShow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.objects];

            for (PFObject *object1 in self.objects) {
                for (PFObject *object2 in objects) {
                    if ([[object1 objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:[object2 objectForKey:@"title"]]) {
                        [arrayToShow removeObject:object1];
                    }
                }
            }

            self.objectsToShowArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayToShow];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];

    }];
    // **********************************


    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSObject * object = [prefs objectForKey:@"category"];
    if(object != nil){
        //object is there
        self.categoryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object];

        [query whereKey:@"category" equalTo:self.categoryString];
    }

    // A pull-to-refresh should always trigger a network request.
    [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    //
    // If there is no network connection, we will hit the cache first.
    if (self.objectsToShowArray.count == 0 || ![[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:@selector(isParseReachable)]) {
        [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];
    }

    return query;
}
```

Same results. In the log it's removing the correct `PFObject`, but in the `UITableView` it's removing the last object. What am I overlooking?

**Getting closer:**

I'm almost there. I figured out the right way to get the results I want, but now I need to add in another layer to my query. Here's my code:

```
PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"myRelation"];
PFQuery *relationQuery = relation.query;

PFRelation *adoptedRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"mySecondRelation"];
PFQuery *adoptedRelationQuery = adoptedRelation.query;

PFQuery *matchQueryOne = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[matchQueryOne whereKey:@"title" matchesKey:@"title" inQuery:relationQuery];

PFQuery *matchQueryTwo = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[matchQueryTwo whereKey:@"title" matchesKey:@"title" inQuery:adoptedRelationQuery];

 PFQuery *queryOne = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
 [queryOne whereKey:@"title" doesNotMatchKey:@"title" inQuery:matchQueryOne];
 [queryOne whereKey:@"title" doesNotMatchKey:@"title" inQuery:matchQueryTwo];
 [queryOne orderByAscending:@"title"];
```

I need to run two relations and combine the results and then get the output.

In this example, only the second case in my queryOne is being hit.

Comment: Is this a pftableviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes, it's a PFQueryTableViewController subclass

Comment: Why are you comparing title?  You can omit the outer loop and simply say `[arrayToShow removeObject:object2]` in the second loop (which will be your only loop)

Comment: Paul: Doesn't work. Doesn't remove anything. Comparing title to match PFObject in the results array to the matching PFObject in self.objects, then if it's a match it needs to be removed from the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

`PFQueryTableViewController` maintains its list of items to be displayed from the query you supply it. You can't make a different query and filter those results without doing away with most of the logic `PFQueryTableViewController` provides for you.

Update the query you supply yo `PFQueryTableViewController` to include clauses which limit the items coming back so you don't need to filter locally.

Comment: Still seeing the last item in the array being removed and not the item that's in the Relation

Comment: You'll need to explain more about what you're doing then, how you're editing the table contents, what requests you send to the server

Comment: I just want to query on Parse Class A, the PFRelation, find the matching PFObjects, and remove them from the array that's showing in the table on the main screen. More detail is added above, with my queryForTable code

Comment: Your latest attempt is the correct approach. Never tried to add 2 sub queries with all the same keys before. Remember that queries, including sub queries, default to 100 items and max at 1000 items and that could be affecting your results...

Comment: Yea, I think the easiest way is going to put all the 'tagged' items into one class and one relation. Right now a user has 2 options (so 2 classes). There's only 40 items total at the moment they can go through.